# Not work jqZoom in colorbox

Tags: jquery, jqzoom

I want to enable `jqzoom` into ajax `colorbox` popup, but it does not properly open.
My code:

```
/*colorbox*/
$('.colorbox1').colorbox({
overlayClose: true,
opacity: 0.5,
rel: "colorbox"
});

/*jqzoom*/
$('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
    zoomType: 'standard',
    lens:true,
    preloadImages: false,
    alwaysOn:false,
    zoomWidth: 250,
    zoomHeight: 250
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for it.

**Reason why not working:**
`jqZoom` render before image load into `Colorbox` popup, so `jqZoom` not able to count exact dimension (width X height) of image.

I got solution below two solution
**Solution 1:** Render/Call `jqZoom` after some timeout in `Colorbox` popup

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
        zoomType: 'standard',
        lens:true,
        preloadImages: false,
        alwaysOn:false,
        zoomWidth: 250,
        zoomHeight: 250
    });
}, 1000);
```

**Solution 2:** Call `jqZoom` after `Colorbox` successfully render

```
$('.colorbox1').colorbox({
    overlayClose: true,
    opacity: 0.5,
    rel: "colorbox",
    onComplete: function(){
        $('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
            zoomType: 'standard',
            lens:true,
            preloadImages: false,
            alwaysOn:false,
            zoomWidth: 250,
            zoomHeight: 250
        });
    }
});
```